# Java.lang.ClassCastException: Activity cannot be cast to interface

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, classcastexception

I am trying to invoke a method named "change_color()" in my one fragment "A" from another fragment "B" using an interface, implemented by the parent activity. When I try to cast my parent activity to the instance of my interface, I get this ClassCastException.

Here's the snippet of fragment "B",

```
    Public class B extends Fragment implements View.onClickListener{
        public attendance_to_history var;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendance_take, 
    container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
                var = (attendance_to_history) getActivity();
            }
```

Here's the code of interface

```
interface attendance_to_history{
public void invoke();}
```

Here's code from my parent activity:

```
    public class tabbed_activity extends AppCompatActivity implements attendance_to_history{
    @Override
    public void invoke() {
        fragment_A  frag = new fragment_A();
        frag.change_color();
    }
}
```

Comment: Besides: learn about java naming conventions. That should read AttendanceToHistory instead ...

Answer (score 0):

```
attendance_to_history connector;
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    connector=(attendance_to_history) activity;
}
```

replace instead for onActivityCreated

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution:
1- in the activity that holds the fragment B, make it `implements attendance_to_history` and override the method `invoke` inside the activity.

then your code will work fine.